# How to connect Android File Picker to a PDF document created in memory?

Tags: android, file, pdf, kotlin, picker

Andorid developer documents explain how you can create a new file using File Picker, which is the same as 'Save As' a file. But they don't seem to explain how you can save a memory created PDF document (or any other type of file) using File Picker. How do I save the document created in memory by the following code, using File Picker?

```
            val document = PdfDocument()
            var pageInfo: PdfDocument.PageInfo = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(700, 1000, 1).create()
            var page: PdfDocument.Page = document.startPage(pageInfo)
            page.canvas.drawCircle(400.0f, 400.0f, 100.0f, paint )
            document.finishPage(page)
            document.Close()
```

Thanks,

Comment: `PdfDocument` is designed for printing. It is not designed for creating PDF files. That being said, [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument) shows that you use `writeTo()` on `PdfDocument` to write to an `OutputStream`. You can use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to get a `Uri` to a document chosen by the user ("File Picker"), then use a `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to get an `OutputStream` for that document. Pass the `OutputStream` to `writeTo()`, then `flush()` and `close()` the stream.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! Maybe it is some wrong thing I did, but somehow this solution doesn't seem to work.Firstly, the code (ContentResolver etc.) does not wait for user to finish entering the file name. Second, the data function of the intent using ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT returns null (not a Uri).

Comment: "Firstly, the code (ContentResolver etc.) does not wait for user to finish entering the file name" -- you would use the `ContentResolver` as part of your `onActivityResult()` processing, when you get the `Uri` back from your `startActivityForResult()` call with your `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` request. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) or your favorite book on Android app development.

Comment: "Second, the data function of the intent using ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT returns null (not a Uri)" -- if the user created a document, you will get the `Uri` for it from the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`. See [this Java sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/tree/v0.6/ContentEditor) or [its Kotlin equivalent](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/tree/v0.6/ContentEditor).

Comment: Thanks! I need to try it.

Comment: Works very well! Appreciate all your help!